# Why does the paint brush style revert back to the old setting the moment I start painting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

In Adobe Illustrator I've changed the paint brush style to something else, (this happens with stroke size too) but the moment I start trying to paint the settings revert back to what they were before I started.

Why is it doing this? How are you supposed to change the stroke/style of the brush if it keeps reverting back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **Appearance Panel Menu** make certain "New Art Has Basic Appearance" is **not** checked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this issue was super frustrating...